# Problem with REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES, in Android

Tags: android, google-play

For about two weeks we have had the problem that Google / Android are rejecting apps for updates with the following statement:

> We found that your app is not compliant with how **REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES** permission is allowed to be used.
> Specifically, the use of the permission is not directly related to the core purpose of the app.

Indeed, some of our apps had included this right in the past, but recent updates (for more than 6 months) no longer.
We have checked and confirmed the current status as follows:

- Manifest controlled
- Searched all APK and plugins
- APK details in the store does not show this right either
- Display of the affected APK using "Sensitive Rights": all old beta versions which are not active

Unfortunately, all our objections and general support requests (also via other Google areas) are consistently ignored.

It is impossible for us to update our apps. Which is extra critical, especially with regard to requirements regarding newer SDK and billing API in two weeks.

How can we obtain help with the issue?

We're not a *very* small publisher, it's about apps with several hundred thousand installations.

Comment: Just to be clear, your app does not request this permission at all?

Comment: Same issue but still no any clear answer, even from google support

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked all of your tracks including open, closed and internal testing? If there's any active APK that violates Google's policy in any of all your tracks, your review will be rejected.